# ios4.3.4: MFMailComposer doesn't send an email, but return MFMailComposeResultSent status

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposer

I am using MFMailComposer. I send email to gmail, MFMailComposer returns MFMailComposeResultSent status. But I don't received any email. I tested on iphone4 with 4.3.4. What I do wrong?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // Set the subject of email
    [mailPicker setSubject:@"Subject"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"Hello from ios";

    // This is not an HTML formatted email
    [mailPicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];


    [self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];

    [mailPicker release];


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) 
 {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
 }
if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
 {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Message has been sent" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
 }
else
 {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
}
```

EDIT: I found this in console :

```
DA|Could not open the lock file at /tmp/DAAccountsLoading.lock. We'll load the accounts anyway, but bad things may happen
```

EDIT2: On iPhone4  with 4.3.4 doesn't work, but on ipod with 4.3 works OK.

Comment: perhaps it gets filtered out as spam ?

Comment: I look at gmail spam but I didn't found any iphone's mail.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the device in order to clear the /tmp directory content? maybe this can remove the lock that is causing you troubles

Answer (score 2):

You do nothing wrong. Check this line from Apple's website:

> `MFMailComposeResultSent` –
>   The email message was queued in the user’s outbox. It is ready to send the next time the user connects to email.

Answer (score 0):

Dont release the mail picker at the specified spot `[mailPicker release];`
.. try using the Autorelease method for the

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
```

the rest is good.

Comment: It does not matter. `mailPicker` will retained when presenting as modal

Comment: @beryllium i was having the same problem so i solved it using this method so can you please suggest something better... i am also willing to know more about it to implement in my applicaitons.