# Sending mail without leaving app

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to send a simple mail from my app without leaving it and I already have the code from other questions in this forum, but my problem is that when I send an email from my app, I have to open the mail program from apple so the mail is being sent.
I get a MFMailComposeResultSent when I send the mail from my app but it stays in the memory or somewhere else until I open the apple-mail-app.
I noticed when searching for my mistake that I never let the user enter his email address and password but they're both saved in the apple-mail-program, that's what I think why I need to open the standard-app.
Any suggestions on how to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can send mails from your app with the MFMailComposer, and you get a comfirmation whether it worked or not.

Comment: It says the mail was sent but it isn't really sent until I open the normal mail-app.

Comment: How do you know that it isn't really sent? I implemented the MFMailComposer into my app and it worked. E-Mails where sent and immediately arrived (without leaving the app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong if you are getting a `MFMailComposeResultSent`. This is not about any username or password of the email account. The documentation says about `MFMailComposeResultSent`: *Send may only be interpreted as a successful queueing of the message for later sending. The actual send will occur when the device is able to send*.

Also your problem became a possible duplicate of: [ios4.3.4: MFMailComposer doesn't send an email, but return MFMailComposeResultSent status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257171/ios4-3-4-mfmailcomposer-doesnt-send-an-email-but-return-mfmailcomposeresultse)